# Application Error rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have uploaded my app to heroku, its a simple app to test a login, it uses a gem named sorcery, but when I test it on heroku, I get Application Error

To upload to heroku I only have do this sequence:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "init"
heroku create
heroku push heroku master
heroku rake db:migrate
```

I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `sorcery' for 
#<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000000266e660>
)
```

Please help me, I think that the gem sorcery is causing this problem, but I dont know what to do.

You can see the website [here](http://powerful-reaches-4543.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work on you localhost?

I see form your list of commands that

```
bundle install
```

is not there.

Make sure you have

```
gem "sorcery"
```

in your gem file

Then do

```
heroku login
```

and

```
bundle install
```

You'll probably get other errors. Go to [Getting Started with Rails 3.x on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) and follow the instructions.

Comment: thanks, the problem was with the gem in the production groupd